# Unable to create java InputStream from javaCV FrameRecorder Class

Tags: java, opencv, ffmpeg, javacv

I am using JavaCV to capture the video from my web camera using FrameRecorder.

I am working to create a library utility class that would provide the webCam video as an 'avi' video InputStream, here I am unable to do so as the FrameRecorder does not provide any such facility, all it takes is a file name and persists the video on the filesystem.
What should I do to generate a java InputStream from FrameRecorder?

Following is the sample code for reference :

```
FrameGrabber frameGrabber = FrameGrabber.createDefault(1);
frameGrabber.start();
IplImage grabbedImage = frameGrabber.grab();
int width = grabbedImage.width();
int height = grabbedImage.height();

FrameRecorder frameRecorder = new FFmpegFrameRecorder("c:\\output.avi", width, height);
frameRecorder.setAudioChannels(frameGrabber.getAudioChannels());
frameRecorder.start();        

int i = 0;
while ((grabbedImage = frameGrabber.grab()) != null && i <= 500) {
    frameRecorder.record(grabbedImage);
    i++;
}

frameRecorder.stop();
frameGrabber.stop();
```

I am open to any other alternatives too ...

thanks in advance

Ashish

Comment: As you say you accept alternatives solutions, could you explain what is your goal? Why you need the AVI stream, and not the raw stream?

Comment: The question mentions merely a container format (avi), but no codec whatsoever is specified. Should it be interpreted the video stream is to be generated uncompressed? If you want to get hold of the raw stream data, details like these are of great importance.

Comment: @DiegoCNascimento : I want the avi stream to be played over at a web browser directly, it won't be possible with raw stream.

Comment: @brunocodutra : consider me a newbie of video streams, i just want a video stream that i can direct to a browser to be played on it, so please answer me on this accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

According to http://code.google.com/p/javacv/source/browse/src/main/java/com/googlecode/javacv/cpp/avformat.java

Seems that the method that is called for writing the frame data is the following:

```
/**
* Write a packet to an output media file.
*
* The packet shall contain one audio or video frame.
* The packet must be correctly interleaved according to the container
* specification, if not then av_interleaved_write_frame must be used.
*
* @param s media file handle
* @param pkt The packet, which contains the stream_index, buf/buf_size,
* dts/pts, ...
* This can be NULL (at any time, not just at the end), in
* order to immediately flush data buffered within the muxer,
* for muxers that buffer up data internally before writing it
* to the output.
* @return < 0 on error, = 0 if OK, 1 if flushed and there is no more data to flush
*/
public static native int av_write_frame(AVFormatContext s, AVPacket pkt);
```

As its native method, your bet will be to redirect the native lib output other than a file,
or using the image data returned to "build" your AVI.

You can use a memory mapped file, but in that case you want continuous capture of video, I don't think it would be a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to use a `FrameRecorder` if your goal is not to create a video file?

The most practical solution I can think of, would be to simply extend `InputStream` using a `FrameGrabber` as backend. Since JavaCV doesn't seem to provide that out of the box, then I'm afraid you'd have to do it yourself.

As described on the [documentation for `InputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html), subclasses of `InputStream` must only implement `public abstract int read()`, however keep in mind it will also most probably be necessary to overwrite other methods too.

A good bet would be to implement `public int read(byte[] b)`.

For reference, a very simple inefficient and unsafe implementation follows.

**Warning not tested**!

```
public int read(byte[] data) throws IOException, BufferUnderflowException, Exception {

    IplImage grabbedImage = frameGrabber.grab();
    if(grabbedImage == null)
        throw <some IOException here>
    grabbedImage.getByteBuffer().get(data);
    return data.length;
}
```

Comment: What it wants, according to the question is the resultant **AVI** stream. For what? I don't know, maybe streaming or the like. But that's not the question.

Comment: @DiegoCNascimento the question is surely not one of the clearest I've ever read, but I get what you mean now. I'll await for a feedback from the OP before I dig any deeper in this.